# adding mongodb authentication breaks connecting via nodejs

Tags: mongodb

I needed to have external access to my mongodb database, so I have removed the bind_ip from the mongod.conf file, and turned on auth. I then added a root user that can access everything, and tried to connect to the database with robomongo - works perfectly. Then I added another user for my nodejs application. I have tried with roles dbAdmin, readWrite, read.... and no matter what I set it to, it will never finish connecting to the DB in nodejs.

User looks like this:

```
db.getUser('node');
{
        "_id" : "admin.node",
        "user" : "node",
        "db" : "admin",
        "roles" : [
                {
                        "role" : "read",
                        "db" : "mydb"
                },
                {
                        "role" : "userAdmin",
                        "db" : "mydb"
                },
                {
                        "role" : "dbAdmin",
                        "db" : "mydb"
                },
                {
                        "role" : "readWrite",
                        "db" : "mydb"
                },
                {
                        "role" : "userAdminAnyDatabase",
                        "db" : "mydb"
                }
        ]
}
```

I can't seem to find anywhere what the proper roles should be.

UPDATE: I wanted to better explain what is happening when it tries to connect. It auths the user just fine, cause if I change the username/pass to something wrong it gives a fail auth error. I also tried adding an event listener for when the connection is "connected", and then run the rest of the script ... and that event is never triggered. It just seems to hang.

UPDATE: Here is the code I am trying to use to connect to the mongodb via mongoose:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://username:password@localhost:27017/database', { auth: { authdb: 'admin' } });
```

Comment: two things: First, please post a code sample so that (at a minimum) others can try this out and debug.  Second, can you connect with that user from the shell and run the operations you want from the shell?  Finally, if this a code issue, then this may be more appropriate for StackOverflow than Serverfault